# How to decode infinite length ending with two zero bytes

Tags: algorithm, decoding

I am decoding an array of bytes which are in `TLV` format (Tag-Length-Value). Sometimes the `Length` of a `Value` is infinite. i.e I have to read the succeeding bytes until I get to **two consequent zero bytes** meaning the end of `Value`. The problem is when the `Value` of a TLV is itself constructed of another TLV with infinite `Length`. I am trying to figure out the best way to decode such TLVs with nested infinite values.

In the following example, each square indicates one byte. After reading `L1`, I realize that the length of `V1` is infinite, which means that I have to read the succeeding bytes until I get to two zero bytes. But the first two zero bytes after `L1` indicate the end of `V3`, not `V1`:

```
                                V3                            
                                .                             
                                |             end of V2       
                                \            -----------
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| T1 | L1 | T2 | L2 | T3 | L3 | 13 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |
+----+----/----+----/----+----/----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
          |         |         |    -----------         -----------
          |         |         |    end of V3           end of V1
          \         |         |
    V1 Starts here  |         |
                    |         |
                    \         |
              V2 Starts here  |
                              |
                              \
                        V3 starts here
```

I need a method/algorithm to detect the end of `V1`. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: That's impossible surely? Or does v2 start with specific identifiying bytes?

Comment: nothing stop v4 starting after the end of v3 right? this is messed up...

Comment: Is it possible to have any more data between the end of V3 and the end of V2?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yes. I think in some circumstances it would be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach is to use a recursive function: each time the function reads until it finds two double zeros, and then returns that position, so that the previous invocation knows where to continue looking for its own double zero terminator.

Alternatively, you could track the nesting level with an integer: increase each time you start reading a new TLV, decrease it when it finds a double zero. The reading is over when the nesting level is zero again.

Comment: How do you find the start of V2 amongst V1?

Comment: It seems to me the start of V2 is just right after the length of V2. I don't see how finding it would be a problem, unless there's some unwritten requirement.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Your are right. V2 is just right after the length of V2.

Answer (score 2):

1. If the value you are encoding is infinite, increment a counter (that starts at 1) each time you encounter another infinite (nested) length.
2. When you reach two zeros, decrement that value.
3. When your counter is zero, you have the last index of the value.

Of course, this only works if inner nested values are end before the outer (as in your example).  If this is not true, I don't think you can differentiate which ends first without more encoding info.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a matching parentheses algorithm with the following :

- Any two zeros is a closing parenthesis
- The first 2 bytes or any two non zero bytes after two zeros is an opening parenthesis.

At the end you can construct a tree where each tag enclosed directly (with one level of containment) is its child. Given this meta data you can do whatever you need...